# What does this hand gesture mean?

Tags: word-request

I was watching [this](https://youtu.be/GjkWN-PG6K0?t=60) video in which someone made a gesture with his hand, he pointed his fingers except the thumb at himself and started moving his hand to the left and to the right.
[image]

I have seen the same gesture made [here](https://youtu.be/cyFx4eMD-pk?t=175) by one of the The X Factor judges when he wanted the music to stop while a contestant was singing.

[image]

Could you tell me what this gesture is called and what it means?

Comment: I’m closing this question because it's not about learning English

Answer (score 1):

That action is used to convey a relatively negative message when trying to be silent, sort of a "stop it right now, or else" or "nope, nope, nope".

The motion looks like cutting one's throat with their hand, which can be like "I will do this to you if you don't stop right now", or "you're dead".  While not to be taken literally (they will not actually do that to you, of course), the message the person is usually trying to convey with this motion is to stop what you are doing immediately.

Comment: To read that much into a still picture of a hand gesture you must be telepathic. My first thought was that in the first picture the person is expressing their own opinion ie. 'for my part I think xyz'. It seems borne out by their interlocutor's gesture too.

Comment: @WS2 I think  the person in the first picture is signalling to a paparazzi or any photographer to stop taking photos. The gesture has to be seen in movement, the palm lies flat and dishes side to side. In the second, I'm guessing the judge is either signalling the public to stop booing or to someone in the crew to stop playing the recording music, which is what the OP describes.

Comment: Yeah...just saw the video. Got it totally wrong. It's an unfunny skit where the guy is messaging to a police offer to get rid of a dead cat(?).